# How do you get the max 100 values of a hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am tasked with returning the top 100 values of a hash in Ruby. I would like to avoid using `.sort_by` because it would be slow for large sets, and would prefer to grab the top 100 hash values first and then sort. How would you approach this?

Comment: 1. Make it work. 2.Make it right/clean/perform. Can you show step 1? And forgot to mention 0. Write tests

Comment: `hash.max_by(100) { |k,v| v }`?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose we have the following hash with 10,000 keys and randomly-generated values:

```
N = 10_000
M = 25_000

h = N.times.with_object({}) { |i,h| h[i] = rand(M) }
  #=> { 0=>23644, 1=>5008, 2=>22792, 3=>3700, 4=>6828,
  #     ...
  #     9995=>2240, 9996=>7923, 9997=>23223, 9998=>11945, 9999=>17913 }
```

The largest 100 values of `h` are obtained as follows:

```
h.values.max(100)
  #=> [24999, 24998, 24997, 24996, 24995, 24991, 24985, 24985, 24983, 24977,
  #    24975, 24972, 24972, 24969, 24969, 24963, 24963, 24958, 24958, 24956,
  #    ...
  #    24801, 24799, 24798, 24798, 24795, 24794, 24785, 24782, 24778, 24778]
```

See (the third form of) [Array#max](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-max).